# I am not able to paste chinese content in textbox using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<input type="text" class="form-control name" name="name" id="focus_me" required maxlength="50" letters-with-space="" ng-trim="false" tabindex="1" ng-model="vm.detail.name" ng-paste="paste($event.originalEvent)" ng-init="vm.detail.name = null">

$scope.paste = function (event,field) {
var item = event.clipboardData.items[0];
 item.getAsString(function (data) {
$scope.pastedData = data;
$scope.$apply();
});
}
```

Input : 继续

here is input , i am not able to paste it into textbox. how to enable it?

Comment: Looks like you need to implement Internationalization i18n at your app. Check AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n#) about it

Answer (score 0):

checkout this https://jsfiddle.net/geekcode/s91t2ryg/11/

I'm able to paste the Chinese content, just pass `$event` instead of `$event.originalEvent`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="ctrl">

<input ng-model="mod" type="text" ng-paste="paste($event)" ng-init="mod = null">
{{mod}}
<input ng-model="mod1" type="text">
</div>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){

$scope.paste = function (event,field) {
var item = event.clipboardData.items[0];
 item.getAsString(function (data) {
$scope.pastedData = data;
$scope.$apply();
});
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: @Allabakash the thing is now content is display and pasted but ng-model is not saving the content once I paste the code into textbox and move to next field it goes disappear.

Comment: can you share if there are any console errors  ?   and share the code for two input boxes as well. I tried with above code which is having two input boxes, it is working fine.